# Converting date into text format

Tags: java, android

How do I convert date into its text format..for ex:if updated today..then instead of date it must show "Today",one day after it must show "Yesterday",and then after two days..it must display the date in general form(*/*/_) on which it was updated..i tried using SimpleDateFormat..but not working..

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

        Date d= new Date(); 

        //Convert Date object to string
        String strDate = sdf.format(d);
        System.out.println("Formated String is " + strDate);


        d  = sdf.parse("31-12-2009");
```

Plz help..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Get current date and check the difference.

Comment: Get the current date and use method of date i.e. is date is `date.before` or `date.after`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class TimeUtils {

      public final static long ONE_SECOND = 1000;
      public final static long SECONDS = 60;

      public final static long ONE_MINUTE = ONE_SECOND * 60;
      public final static long MINUTES = 60;

      public final static long ONE_HOUR = ONE_MINUTE * 60;
      public final static long HOURS = 24;

      public final static long ONE_DAY = ONE_HOUR * 24;

      private TimeUtils() {
      }

      /**
       * converts time (in milliseconds) to human-readable format
       *  "<w> days, <x> hours, <y> minutes and (z) seconds"
       */
      public static String millisToLongDHMS(long duration) {
        StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();
        long temp = 0;
        if (duration >= ONE_SECOND) {
          temp = duration / ONE_DAY;
          if (temp > 0) {
            duration -= temp * ONE_DAY;
            res.append(temp).append(" day").append(temp > 1 ? "s" : "")
               .append(duration >= ONE_MINUTE ? ", " : "");
          }

          temp = duration / ONE_HOUR;
          if (temp > 0) {
            duration -= temp * ONE_HOUR;
            res.append(temp).append(" hour").append(temp > 1 ? "s" : "")
               .append(duration >= ONE_MINUTE ? ", " : "");
          }

          temp = duration / ONE_MINUTE;
          if (temp > 0) {
            duration -= temp * ONE_MINUTE;
            res.append(temp).append(" minute").append(temp > 1 ? "s" : "");
          }

          if (!res.toString().equals("") && duration >= ONE_SECOND) {
            res.append(" and ");
          }

          temp = duration / ONE_SECOND;
          if (temp > 0) {
            res.append(temp).append(" second").append(temp > 1 ? "s" : "");
          }
          return res.toString();
        } else {
          return "0 second";
        }
      }


      public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(millisToLongDHMS(123));
        System.out.println(millisToLongDHMS((5 * ONE_SECOND) + 123));
        System.out.println(millisToLongDHMS(ONE_DAY + ONE_HOUR));
        System.out.println(millisToLongDHMS(ONE_DAY + 2 * ONE_SECOND));
        System.out.println(millisToLongDHMS(ONE_DAY + ONE_HOUR + (2 * ONE_MINUTE)));
        System.out.println(millisToLongDHMS((4 * ONE_DAY) + (3 * ONE_HOUR)
            + (2 * ONE_MINUTE) + ONE_SECOND));
        System.out.println(millisToLongDHMS((5 * ONE_DAY) + (4 * ONE_HOUR)
            + ONE_MINUTE + (23 * ONE_SECOND) + 123));
        System.out.println(millisToLongDHMS(42 * ONE_DAY));
        /*
          output :
                0 second
                5 seconds
                1 day, 1 hour
                1 day and 2 seconds
                1 day, 1 hour, 2 minutes
                4 days, 3 hours, 2 minutes and 1 second
                5 days, 4 hours, 1 minute and 23 seconds
                42 days
         */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [PrettyTime](http://ocpsoft.com/prettytime/) library.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [Comparision of dates](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compare-dates-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

For comparing dates please see this entry: [datecompare](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compare-dates-in-java/)

Comment: While that link may contain the answer, it is preferable to include a summary as well, rather than just a link. That way the answer will still be useful to others if the link breaks or changes.

Comment: Link only answers often get deleted, so now is as good a time as any :)

Comment: ya but i didnt understand your comment

Comment: Which one? Basically I just suggested you expand your answer so it is more than just a link. Otherwise, it might get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement your own logic based on the time difference and use the corresponding date format.

Lets assume you are getting a date from a server.
Get the device's time and compare to your date.
For your requirements there will be two cases.

1. The difference between the two date is less then a day, then return "Today" string.
2. The difference between the two date is grater then a day then use the Simple Date format to format your date as you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class App {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); 
    public static long ms, s, m, h, d, w;

    static {
        ms = 1;
        s = ms * 1000;
        m = s * 60;
        h = m * 60;
        d = h * 24;
        w = d * 7;
    }

    public App() {
           Date now = new Date();
           Date old = new Date();

           try {
               old = sdf.parse("12-11-2013");
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           long diff = now.getTime() - old.getTime();

           if (diff < this.d) {
               System.out.println("Today");
           }
           else if (diff > this.d && diff < this.d*2) {
               System.out.println("Yesterday");
           }

           System.out.println("Difference: " + msToHms(diff));
    }

    public String msToHms(long ms) {
        int seconds = (int) (ms / this.s) % 60 ;
        int minutes = (int) ((ms / this.m) % 60);
        int hours   = (int) ((ms / this.h) % 24);

        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App();
    }
}
```

Output

```
Yesterday
Difference: 07:11:22
```